# reading multiple files in a directory as python list

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to read multiple files in my directory as python list. The txt files contains list of IDs.
eg., H104.txt

```
CZ104
Cz509
T3G63
```

Im sharing the script I wrote,

```
files = ["H104.txt","H905.txt","H920B1.txt","T636.txt"]
# shell script for getting file list
#  ls | tr ' ' ',' | tr '\n' ',' | sed -r 's/[^,]+/"&"/g'


f = ["H104","H905","H920B1","T636"]
i = 0

while i < len(f):
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'r') as onefile:
            f[i] = onefile.readlines()
    i += 1

print(H104)
```

I want to read these multiple files using their respective file names as a variable. The above script gives me Nameerror `NameError: name 'H104' is not defined`.

The output I want,
`["CZ104","Cz509","T3G63"]`

Comment: Can you specify the output you need? I don't understand why you need for loop inside a while loop.

Comment: I want to read each file as a list. I would add the output as well with my question.

Comment: You are telling it to print the contents of a variable with name "H104", that variable does not exist, hence the name error.  Also, it seems like you are reading just the first line of the file... maybe not what you want if your files have multiple lines.

Comment: @Pocketsand Yes, I understand the error. But How can I assign the content of the file into the variable in this loop. I changed the ``` readlines() ``` . I wrote that by mistake. I want all lines. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to read these multiple files using their respective file names as a variable.

It's a bit hard to tell, but I think you want a dictionary here. For example:

```
# Fill the dict: keys are filenames, values are lists of lines.
file_lines = {}
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'rt') as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
        file_lines[filename] = lines

# Access each file by its key in the dict.
print(file_lines['H104.txt'])
```

If you don't mind that each line ends with a `\n` newline character, you can also simplify the reading down to `lines = file.readlines()`.